# Android SQLite Database "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

I was just started to learn Android programming and I was trying to make a simple Android SQLite database and I encountered some error in my **".java"** files in the **"src"** such as "R cannot be resolved to a variable" and an error in my xml at **menu** folder say that **"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').  database_android_satu.xml   /DatabaseAndroid/res/menu   line 5  Android AAPT Problem"**
I deeply gratitude for your kindness of your answer and maybe some advice..

here is my .java files :

```
package com.db.satu;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class DatabaseAndroidSatu extends Activity {
    DatabaseManager dm;
    EditText nama, hobi;
    Button addBtn;
    TableLayout tabel4data;// tabel for data

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dm = new DatabaseManager(this);
    tabel4data = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
    nama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inNama);
    hobi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inHobi);
    addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    simpKamuta();
    }
});
    updateTable();
    }

    protected void simpKamuta() {
    try {
    dm.addRow(nama.getText().toString(),hobi.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
    nama.getText().toString() + ", berhasil disimpan",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updateTable();
    kosongkanField();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "gagal simpan, " +
        e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
    protected void kosongkanField(){
    nama.setText("");
    hobi.setText("");
    }
    protected void updateTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (tabel4data.getChildCount() > 1) {
    tabel4data.removeViewAt(1);
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = dm.ambilSemuaBaris();//

    for (int posisi = 0; posisi < data.size(); posisi++) {
    TableRow tabelBaris = new TableRow(this);
    ArrayList<Object> baris = data.get(posisi);

    TextView idTxt = new TextView(this);
    idTxt.setText(baris.get(0).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(idTxt);

    TextView namaTxt = new TextView(this);
    namaTxt.setText(baris.get(1).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(namaTxt);

    TextView hobiTxt = new TextView(this);
    hobiTxt.setText(baris.get(2).toString());
    tabelBaris.addView(hobiTxt);

    tabel4data.addView(tabelBaris);
    }
}}
```

here is my .xml files that located in menu folder of the project :
its contain an error: **"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').    database_android_satu.xml   /DatabaseAndroid/res/menu   line 5  Android AAPT Problem"**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.db.satu.DatabaseAndroidSatu" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: your xml have some errors.

Comment: can you verify that your /res/values/strings.xml have <string name="action_settings"><<your definition>></string>

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: You really should run a full Gradle build, then look in Project explorer perspective in Android Studio to see which of your resource files are underlined in red (have errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oftentimes when `R.java` is not working properly, it is because you are having an issue in one of your XML files. In this case, your `menu.xml` file is causing the issue. It states that you are referencing a String named `action_settings`, but this String has not yet been defined.

To fix this, open your `strings.xml` file and define a String, using `<string name="action_settings">MyString</string>`.

Example in response to your comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Masukkan nama dan hobi</string>
    <string name="app_name">Database Android #1</string>
    <string name="btnAddtxt">Add</string>
    <string name="namaLabel">Nama</string>
    <string name="hobiLabel">hobi</string>
    <string name="nomorLabel">No.</string>
    <string name="nomorLabel">No.</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: this is what in my string.xml can you check them?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
 <string name="hello">Masukkan nama dan hobi</string>
 <string name="app_name">Database Android #1</string>
 <string name="btnAddtxt">Add</string>
 <string name="namaLabel">Nama</string>
 <string name="hobiLabel">hobi</string>
 <string name="nomorLabel">No.</string>
 <string name="nomorLabel">No.</string>
</resources>

Comment: Yes, so you need to add in the action_strings. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: anyway why when I'm about to run this app it say unfortunately "app name" has stop. why is it like that?

Comment: Check your `LogCat`. It will contain the stack trace that is printed when the application is crashing. However, that sounds like a separate issue and if you need continued assistance with it, it should be posted in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `<string name="action_settings">Some string</string>` in strings.xml file.